# How can I tell when a machine tries to get a new DHCP address?

Tags: dhcp, logs

I’m having an issue where one of my servers is losing connectivity.  I suspect this is due to it trying to renew it’s DHCP lease. Does an Ubuntu server keep logs about when it tries to get a new address?

Comment: who is the DHCP server for the clients? is another ubuntu the dhcp server as well as the client? do you have a dhcp fixed lease or is it dynamic? whats the timeout for the dhcp lease?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Ubuntu version 15.04 and above, you should be able to see that with

```
journalctl | grep -i 'dhcp'
```

or more specifically

```
journalctl | grep -i 'DHCPREQUEST'
```

You can also continuously show output in follow mode with `-f` flag with filtering for the specific `systemd` unit, and unless you're using custom dhcp client, that information should be under Network Manager unit by default:

```
journalctl -f '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager'
```

to see when your server tries to send a DHCP renewal request. Whether or not it's related to loosing connectivity - it may need other troubleshooting, potentially on your router side.

Answer (score 1):

To get a full view of `dhclient`

```
journalctl -t dhclient
```

then press <kbd>/</kbd> and search for `DHCPREQUEST`.